Why isn't my build generating PDB file for the main executable?

My build settings above
And below you can see pdb generated for the unitycrashhandler / unityplayer / windows player, but no corresponding pdb for myproject.exe? Anyone know why?


I have a folder called "GAMENAME_BackUpThisFolder_ButDontShipItWithYourGame" where I have "/Managed/GAMENAME.assembly.pdb" and *.dll
Do you have such a folder? Do you have scripts in your project yet? I do have created AssemblyDefinitions for my scripts, that groups them in separate dlls, so my result may differ from yours.

this is just a small test project to simply reproduce the issue. yes it has a script, but no there is no *butdontshipwithyourgame folder. in my main actual game that i need to get working there does exist a folder like this, but it doesnt have any pdbs in it. i also suspect your GAMENAME.assembly.pdb isnt linked directly to your executable?
